# Selenium click() method

Tags: selenium, click

I am using Selenium 2.25.0 to automate GUI testing for a web application. This application has a setup wizard that takes the user through a certain set of forms and configures an appliance  accordingly. Forms are dynamically generated and have a common set of back/next buttons. At a particular page the next button does not click().

I have verified that the Dimensions(size()) of this button are > 0. I can see the button getting focussed, but it does not click. Also, click() method does not throw any exception.

Ultimately, the explicit wait on the next line of code times out and my test fails. Browser is Firefox and until recently, the same code used to work fine.

This seems to be a known issue. In that case, is there a workaround ?
The solution shall work with Firefox/Chrome and IE.

Some one suggested to use

```
driver.manage.Timeout().PageLoadTimeouts()
```

But isn't that redundant if the code already has an explicit wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html, also make sure you are [focused correctly on the correct frame](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html).

Comment: I used the first link and changed click() method call to new Actions(driver).click().perform() and it worked, but I will like to know why the click() method gives non deterministic results. Thanks for answering.

Comment: It breaks again, at the same place :) Please share more info, if any one has any. I will like to read more.

Comment: I know you probably have done this, but have you checked the form manually with the same conditions (user account etc.) to make sure that the next button does in fact work? It could be that your test found a legitimate bug.

Comment: I displayed the Dimensions using size() method just before click(). Both height and width are greater than 0. So, the Web Element is being recognized.

Answer (score 2):

After your code finds the button, and before it clicks it, you should insert a line that assigns the element's location_once_scrolled_into_view member variable to a variable, even if you never use it. I don't know why, but that will ensure that the click actually hits the mark. (We use it all over our test scripts, and it seems to do the job.)

Example:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id("MyButton")
ScrollLocation = button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
button.click()
```